# What is the use case for sharing a term between multiple taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

The `WP_Term::get_instance()` method, used by `get_term()` and presumably other core API functions, accepts an optional `$taxonomy` arg that is "only used for disambiguating potentially shared terms."

What is the use case for sharing terms like this? Is it possible to share a term between taxonomies with base WordPress functionality alone, without implementing custom hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helpful folks on WordPress IRC pointed me to this article, which answered my question:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/

> In WordPress 4.2, shared taxonomy terms – those items in the wp_terms table that are shared between multiple taxonomies – will be split into separate terms when one of the shared terms is updated. This change ([31418](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/31418)) fixes one of WordPress’s most irksome bugs, and is a critical step in our ongoing taxonomy roadmap.

Furthermore:

> The vast majority of terms are not shared between taxonomies; shared terms themselves are an odd edge case.

So basically, this use-case has not been supported for a long time, and was rare to begin with.